# How to retrieve nutrition information?

Tags: walmart-api

I am trying to extract nutrition information for an item using the [Walmart Open API](https://developer.walmartlabs.com/).

**Example:**

I am using:

http://api.walmartlabs.com/v1/items/10319333

But the response does not contain item specifications and Nutrition facts as listed on:

https://www.walmart.com/ip/Green-Giant-Cut-Asparagus-Spears-14-5-Oz/10319333

How can I retrieve the complete information about the item using the API?

Here is the response from the API:

```
    {
"itemId": 10319333,
"parentItemId": 10319333,
"name": "Green Giant Cut Asparagus Spears, 14.5 Oz",
"salePrice": 1.98,
"upc": "020000103266",
"categoryPath": "Food/Meal Solutions, Grains & Pasta/Canned Goods/Canned Vegetables",
"shortDescription": "&lt;p&gt;Our love for vegetables began over 100 years ago in Le Sueur, Minnesota. Today, we still have fourth-generation farmers who picked each crop at the peak of perfection. That's how we make vegetables like Green Giant 50% Less Sodium Cut Asparagus Spears unforgettable. That's Green Giant.&lt;/p&gt;",
"longDescription": "&lt;div&gt;&lt;b&gt;Product Features&lt;/b&gt;&lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt;50% less sodium than our regular asparagus&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Picked at the Peak of Perfection&trade;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ul&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;Can - Recyclable&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;Please recycle&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;&copy;2011 General Mills",
"brandName": "Green Giant",
"thumbnailImage": "https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/1b850b71-b8e7-4ccc-8cf1-fc3bbe493662_1.392a7fb59712d4025fabf0fe500875fd.jpeg?odnHeight=100&odnWidth=100&odnBg=FFFFFF",
"mediumImage": "https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/1b850b71-b8e7-4ccc-8cf1-fc3bbe493662_1.392a7fb59712d4025fabf0fe500875fd.jpeg?odnHeight=180&odnWidth=180&odnBg=FFFFFF",
"largeImage": "https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/1b850b71-b8e7-4ccc-8cf1-fc3bbe493662_1.392a7fb59712d4025fabf0fe500875fd.jpeg?odnHeight=450&odnWidth=450&odnBg=FFFFFF",
"productTrackingUrl": "http://linksynergy.walmart.com/fs-bin/click?id=|LSNID|&offerid=223073.7200&type=14&catid=8&subid=0&hid=7200&tmpid=1082&RD_PARM1=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.walmart.com%252Fip%252FGreen-Giant-Cut-Asparagus-Spears-14-5-Oz%252F10319333%253Faffp1%253DOv_GAFGulDw0GvEmd2eUnr97kgxCP42RJUVLSEURtzs%2526affilsrc%253Dapi",
"ninetySevenCentShipping": false,
"standardShipRate": 5.99,
"size": "14.5 oz",
"marketplace": false,
"shipToStore": true,
"freeShipToStore": true,
"modelNumber": "10326",
"productUrl": "http://c.affil.walmart.com/t/api01?l=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.walmart.com%2Fip%2FGreen-Giant-Cut-Asparagus-Spears-14-5-Oz%2F10319333%3Faffp1%3DOv_GAFGulDw0GvEmd2eUnr97kgxCP42RJUVLSEURtzs%26affilsrc%3Dapi%26veh%3Daff%26wmlspartner%3Dreadonlyapi",
"customerRating": "3.333",
"numReviews": 12,
"customerRatingImage": "http://i2.walmartimages.com/i/CustRating/3_3.gif",
"categoryNode": "976759_976794_976785",
"rhid": "34052",
"bundle": false,
"clearance": false,
"preOrder": false,
"stock": "Available",
"attributes": {
    "mainimageurl": "https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/1b850b71-b8e7-4ccc-8cf1-fc3bbe493662_1.392a7fb59712d4025fabf0fe500875fd.jpeg",
    "paperWoodIndicator": "N",
    "size": "14.5 oz"
},
"addToCartUrl": "http://c.affil.walmart.com/t/api01?l=http%3A%2F%2Faffil.walmart.com%2Fcart%2FaddToCart%3Fitems%3D10319333%7C1%26affp1%3DOv_GAFGulDw0GvEmd2eUnr97kgxCP42RJUVLSEURtzs%26affilsrc%3Dapi%26veh%3Daff%26wmlspartner%3Dreadonlyapi",
"affiliateAddToCartUrl": "http://linksynergy.walmart.com/fs-bin/click?id=|LSNID|&offerid=223073.7200&type=14&catid=8&subid=0&hid=7200&tmpid=1082&RD_PARM1=http%253A%252F%252Faffil.walmart.com%252Fcart%252FaddToCart%253Fitems%253D10319333%257C1%2526affp1%253DOv_GAFGulDw0GvEmd2eUnr97kgxCP42RJUVLSEURtzs%2526affilsrc%253Dapi",
"freeShippingOver35Dollars": true,
"giftOptions": {
    "allowGiftWrap": false,
    "allowGiftMessage": false,
    "allowGiftReceipt": false
},
"imageEntities": [{
    "thumbnailImage": "https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/1b850b71-b8e7-4ccc-8cf1-fc3bbe493662_1.392a7fb59712d4025fabf0fe500875fd.jpeg?odnHeight=100&odnWidth=100&odnBg=FFFFFF",
    "mediumImage": "https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/1b850b71-b8e7-4ccc-8cf1-fc3bbe493662_1.392a7fb59712d4025fabf0fe500875fd.jpeg?odnHeight=180&odnWidth=180&odnBg=FFFFFF",
    "largeImage": "https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/1b850b71-b8e7-4ccc-8cf1-fc3bbe493662_1.392a7fb59712d4025fabf0fe500875fd.jpeg?odnHeight=450&odnWidth=450&odnBg=FFFFFF",
    "entityType": "PRIMARY"
}, {
    "thumbnailImage": "https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/68e3a7af-80b9-4105-9c21-ba71b74f4353_2.c75c83a5be81589992eb53bc87f67636.png?odnHeight=100&odnWidth=100&odnBg=FFFFFF",
    "mediumImage": "https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/68e3a7af-80b9-4105-9c21-ba71b74f4353_2.c75c83a5be81589992eb53bc87f67636.png?odnHeight=180&odnWidth=180&odnBg=FFFFFF",
    "largeImage": "https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/68e3a7af-80b9-4105-9c21-ba71b74f4353_2.c75c83a5be81589992eb53bc87f67636.png?odnHeight=450&odnWidth=450&odnBg=FFFFFF",
    "entityType": "SECONDARY"
}, {
    "thumbnailImage": "https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/a08ea154-7462-47b1-918e-bcc7957ff837_2.744c794fad8f851d8ee189fd26400cdf.png?odnHeight=100&odnWidth=100&odnBg=FFFFFF",
    "mediumImage": "https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/a08ea154-7462-47b1-918e-bcc7957ff837_2.744c794fad8f851d8ee189fd26400cdf.png?odnHeight=180&odnWidth=180&odnBg=FFFFFF",
    "largeImage": "https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/a08ea154-7462-47b1-918e-bcc7957ff837_2.744c794fad8f851d8ee189fd26400cdf.png?odnHeight=450&odnWidth=450&odnBg=FFFFFF",
    "entityType": "SECONDARY"
}, {
    "thumbnailImage": "https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/771afb55-b68f-4c7d-b689-b414acd7513c_2.b8fe2bba6a0cf1fac33f9a74697d6325.png?odnHeight=100&odnWidth=100&odnBg=FFFFFF",
    "mediumImage": "https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/771afb55-b68f-4c7d-b689-b414acd7513c_2.b8fe2bba6a0cf1fac33f9a74697d6325.png?odnHeight=180&odnWidth=180&odnBg=FFFFFF",
    "largeImage": "https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/771afb55-b68f-4c7d-b689-b414acd7513c_2.b8fe2bba6a0cf1fac33f9a74697d6325.png?odnHeight=450&odnWidth=450&odnBg=FFFFFF",
    "entityType": "SECONDARY"
}, {
    "thumbnailImage": "https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/93bc899a-9ff1-4452-83ce-bbf4924870bd_1.19b09eb104988ac2d457d7950d4e4dc6.png?odnHeight=100&odnWidth=100&odnBg=FFFFFF",
    "mediumImage": "https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/93bc899a-9ff1-4452-83ce-bbf4924870bd_1.19b09eb104988ac2d457d7950d4e4dc6.png?odnHeight=180&odnWidth=180&odnBg=FFFFFF",
    "largeImage": "https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/93bc899a-9ff1-4452-83ce-bbf4924870bd_1.19b09eb104988ac2d457d7950d4e4dc6.png?odnHeight=450&odnWidth=450&odnBg=FFFFFF",
    "entityType": "SECONDARY"
}, {
    "thumbnailImage": "https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/8578bf1f-dd3b-4099-8e05-3749e3f0fefe_1.d0e3a6e567368d4adf9e8e173805db5f.jpeg?odnHeight=100&odnWidth=100&odnBg=FFFFFF",
    "mediumImage": "https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/8578bf1f-dd3b-4099-8e05-3749e3f0fefe_1.d0e3a6e567368d4adf9e8e173805db5f.jpeg?odnHeight=180&odnWidth=180&odnBg=FFFFFF",
    "largeImage": "https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/8578bf1f-dd3b-4099-8e05-3749e3f0fefe_1.d0e3a6e567368d4adf9e8e173805db5f.jpeg?odnHeight=450&odnWidth=450&odnBg=FFFFFF",
    "entityType": "SECONDARY"
}, {
    "thumbnailImage": "https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/76b526ed-d0b7-4c14-8930-9033f5580ac0_2.470873a329465256bf00e26892dbeadf.png?odnHeight=100&odnWidth=100&odnBg=FFFFFF",
    "mediumImage": "https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/76b526ed-d0b7-4c14-8930-9033f5580ac0_2.470873a329465256bf00e26892dbeadf.png?odnHeight=180&odnWidth=180&odnBg=FFFFFF",
    "largeImage": "https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/76b526ed-d0b7-4c14-8930-9033f5580ac0_2.470873a329465256bf00e26892dbeadf.png?odnHeight=450&odnWidth=450&odnBg=FFFFFF",
    "entityType": "SECONDARY"
}, {
    "thumbnailImage": "https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/63927f3d-912b-427e-b929-921c11d52b7c_1.c26810bb207887cf1e11ec0f3a57ec0a.jpeg?odnHeight=100&odnWidth=100&odnBg=FFFFFF",
    "mediumImage": "https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/63927f3d-912b-427e-b929-921c11d52b7c_1.c26810bb207887cf1e11ec0f3a57ec0a.jpeg?odnHeight=180&odnWidth=180&odnBg=FFFFFF",
    "largeImage": "https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/63927f3d-912b-427e-b929-921c11d52b7c_1.c26810bb207887cf1e11ec0f3a57ec0a.jpeg?odnHeight=450&odnWidth=450&odnBg=FFFFFF",
    "entityType": "SECONDARY"
}],
"offerType": "ONLINE_AND_STORE",
"isTwoDayShippingEligible": true,
"availableOnline": true
```

}

Comment: Can you share what the response?

Comment: FYI https://developer.walmart.com/ only lists v2 and v3 APIs...?